# Formatting DIVs horizontally

Tags: html, css

I am having some trouble formatting DIVs. I'm not much of a web guy so sorry if this question is a little silly.

Currently in my web page I have a Form with 3 divs inside. One div lays on-top, and the other two lay abreast:

[image: As seen in this simple illustration.]

However if the bottom two divs are both set to 50% width of the container they will stack vertically. If set to 50% and 49% they will stay abreast but there is a large ugly gap:

[image: Shown Here]

Here is a simplified version of the HTML, the styling is included.

```
<form id="Form1" style="width:100%">
    <div id="Div1">
        <table id="Table1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" width="100%">
            Table Stuff
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="Div2" BorderWidth="1" Style="display: inline-block;
    width: 49%; float: left;">
        <table id="Table2" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" width="100%">
            Table Stuff
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="Div3" BorderWidth="1" Style="display: inline-block;
    width: 50%; float: Right;">
        <table id="Table3" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" width="100%">
            Table Stuff
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The width doesn't include the border by default. Try setting `box-sizing: border-box` on your divs and they should sit side by side at 50% width.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. @delinear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [flexbox](https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-visual-guide-to-css3-flexbox-properties).

Use tables for tabular data and not layout.

You will need to account for the width the border adds to your element's width. The simplest fix is to apply [`box-sizing: border-box;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) to those elements. This will tell the browser to include the border when calculating the width.

i.e. If you tell an element to have a width and height of 200px and give it a 5px border, **without** `box-sizing: border-box;` your element will have a width and height of 210px ( 5px + 200px + 5px ). **With** `box-sizing: border-box;` the border is included in the width so the width and height remain 200px and the border is placed within, reducing the available space for content.

```css
div {
  min-height: 100px;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div:nth-child( 1 ) {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

div:nth-child( 2 ) {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

div:nth-child( 3 ) {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score -2):

That's because the border-width. If you puts 50% + 50% + borders is more than 100%. I don't remember right now but exist a css property or something similar that's allows to the border to be included to the % of width. That will fix your problem.

Comment: box-sizing: border-box; That's the css property you need as I said before, my answer is practictly the same than the accepted answer by the owner. Not sure why you put negative valoration to my answer when I said the same but whatever... I'm happy you could understand the solution